# Use JKS keystore for public key authentication with Ganymed SSH

Tags: java, ssh, keystore, private-key, public-key

I'm trying to extract a private key from a java keystore and then feed it to Ganymed SSH in order to establish a connection with public key authentication. It is however refusing to connect.

I can successfully connect through Cygwin (`ssh -i`) with files generated by the following program, but the program itself is unable to get past authentication on the same machine. What am I doing wrong?

I don't get an exception, [Connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(String, char[], String)](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.html#authenticateWithPublicKey%28java.lang.String,%20char[],%20java.lang.String%29) simply returns false, so this should not be a formatting problem. It does not matter if I leave the private key unencrypted, the result is the same. Also, I was able to connect with a program similar to this with files generated by putty-gen and ssh-keygen.

You will need the following to compile (bouncycastle and ganymed):

- [bcprov](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-151.jar)
- [bcpkix](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar)
- [ganymed-ssh2](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/ethz/ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/262/ganymed-ssh2-262.jar)

Generate the keystore with:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks -alias myalias -storepass password -keypass password -keyalg RSA -dname CN=myalias,O=example.com -storetype JKS -validity 365 -v
```

Code (expects host and port as args and the above keystore in working directory):

```java
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.DSAParams;
import java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMEncryptor;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMEncryptorBuilder;

public class KeystoreGanymedSSH {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        String keystorePath = "keystore.jks";
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        String alias = "myalias";

        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        // keystore init
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream in;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Generate keystore using this command:");
            System.out.println("keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks"
                    + " -alias myalias -storepass password -keypass password"
                    + " -keyalg RSA -dname CN=myalias,O=example.com -storetype"
                    + " JKS -validity 365 -v");
            throw ex;
        }
        try {
            keystore.load(in, password);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // get public key in OpenSSH format
        String authorizedKeysEntry = genAuthorizedKeysEntry(keystore, alias);
        if (authorizedKeysEntry == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not generate authorized_keys entry");
        }
        System.out.println("Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file (always same):");
        System.out.println(authorizedKeysEntry);
        System.out.println();

        Writer writer;

        // write to file
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("authorized_keys")), "UTF-8");
        try {
            writer.write(authorizedKeysEntry);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }

        // obtain PEM encrypted char[]
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password);
        writer = new CharArrayWriter();
        JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(writer);
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        PEMEncryptor encryptor = new JcePEMEncryptorBuilder("DES-EDE3-CBC")
                .setSecureRandom(random).build(password);
        pw.writeObject(key, encryptor);
        pw.flush();
        char[] privateKey = ((CharArrayWriter)writer).toCharArray();

        System.out.println("Encrypted private key (changes on each run):");
        System.out.println(new String(privateKey));
        String name = "RSA".equals(key.getAlgorithm()) ? "id_rsa" : "id_dsa";
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(new File(name)), "UTF-8");
        try {
            writer.write(privateKey);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }

        // attempt ganymed connection   
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + host + ":" + port);
            connection = new Connection(host, port);        
            connection.connect(); // no known_hosts

            if (!connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(alias, "publickey")) {
                System.out.println("Public key auth is not available.");
                return;
            }

            boolean result = connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(
                    alias, privateKey, new String(password));

            System.out.println(result ? "Authentication success." : "Authentication failure.");
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    }

    private static String genAuthorizedKeysEntry(
            KeyStore keystore, String alias) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Certificate[] chain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        if (chain == null || chain.length <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        PublicKey publicKey = chain[0].getPublicKey();
        if ("RSA".equals(publicKey.getAlgorithm())) {
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            String type = "ssh-rsa";
            dos.writeInt(type.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
            dos.write(type.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] exponent = rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(exponent.length);
            dos.write(exponent);
            byte[] modulus = rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(modulus.length);
            dos.write(modulus);
            String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
                    baos.toByteArray());
            return type + " " + encoded + " " + alias;
        } else if ("DSA".equals(publicKey.getAlgorithm())) {
            DSAPublicKey dsaPublicKey = (DSAPublicKey) publicKey;
            DSAParams params = dsaPublicKey.getParams();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            String type = "ssh-dss";
            dos.writeInt(type.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
            dos.write(type.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] p = params.getP().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(p.length);
            dos.write(p);
            byte[] q = params.getQ().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(q.length);
            dos.write(q);
            byte[] g = params.getG().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(g.length);
            dos.write(g);
            byte[] y = dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray();
            dos.writeInt(y.length);
            dos.write(y);
            String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
                    baos.toByteArray());
            return type + " " + encoded + " " + alias;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file (always same):
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCJLXgRaVdbZNuCsTgUsw2UPGdEA4La8ggQZWkevgAEMrgF+YYT2uN6BYDgD7hzs3ZTLXz2KUQLkMe7xLvimAsg6YXUi46IGEkTSOBFR0yYj+12O2BNbAxOXLIDIMBK5bsDwnuOsFedbeILFU4DaV+igJKO1zHWNbmbmd4RlfrIgH7Blfce8zSVkEdLkqEmydbg4xmj6r+MlzA5HSNZJILivb1XYNnoLjRH1SwUC8Rj6bjgBdNEXLOH0FNpCatHk9R00GaSZjcDZRKNAKnBSEIpw01TKaJlyQUTGqYGjK7UIbbafwMuYKR1rIzkyh4Usxvd3FvMdmKQSUeCnZU296YF myalias

Encrypted private key (changes on each run):
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,86DF7B50D4E319F6
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Connecting to 10.0.3.138:22
Authentication failure.
```

**Edit01**

I've tried this with [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) and all of them fail to connect. There has to be something wrong with the above code for private key extraction. What baffles me is that I can connect with `ssh -i`. Also, if I load the above private key into putty-gen, I get the same authorized_keys string as in output from my program (already present in my remote machine's `.ssh/authorized_keys`). But if I save it as a ppk file and then try to establish a putty session with it, it doesn't go through either (server refused our key).

Answer (score 4):

**There's noting wrong with the code I posted.** It was just a huge fail on my part.

I used the keystore alias name as a username which *did not exist as a user account* on the remote linux box. After creating the account, everything works. I was editing the wrong `authorized_keys` file (on some other account) and expecting it to work through some obscure dark magic known only to leprechauns, unicorns and apparently my brain.

As for why it worked when I did `ssh -i`... Defaults. Stupid defaults. I did not specify a username at all so it defaulted to the one Cygwin was currently using and it just so happened that it had the same name as the account on the remote where I was editing the `authorized_keys` file.

Great. Awesome. Just..perfect. I need to go find a bridge to throw myself off from now.

Doing what I do in my code works with ganymed, jsch and sshj (with some small modifications for the other two APIs).